# convert list to string?

Tags: python, string, list

I was wondering if there was a way to convert my List into a String.

Example: Is there a way to convert `MyList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` to `MyString = "abcde"` ?

Reason: I am trying to make words out of those 5 letters: bag, bad, cab, bed...

I tried creating a Label that shows `MyList._contains_("bad")` but it doesn't work since "bad" is not in the list as a whole, but 'b', 'a', 'd' are in the list individually.

So I thought if I convert the entire List to one String, I would be able to use something like
`MyString._contains_("bad")` and have the word show in the Label.

So is there a way to convert all this to one string?
Or is there a more efficient way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Note it's two underscores - `__contains__`

Comment: Once joined, you can use `bad in mystring` rather than `mystring.__contains__("bad")`

Comment: I voted to re-open on the grounds that the OP asked an xy problem. Their actual problem was "How do I find if all characters in a string are contained in a list of characters?"

Comment: Note that your method won't work anyway, since `'bad' in 'abcde'` is `False`. Try instead: `for word in wordlist: all(letter in MyString for letter in word)`

Comment: `from collections import Counter;bool(Counter'bed')-Counter('abcdef')`.  Note that `bool(Counter'cede')-Counter('abcdef')` would be evaluate to `False` because `'abcdef'` does not have two `'e'`s in it.  If you wanted that to be `True` replace `Counter` with `set`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski a bit obscure, but far more correct since `all(letter in 'ab' for letter in 'abba')` is `True` when it certainly ought to be `False`.

Comment: thanks for all the answers. I searched a lot and couldn't find any results on this matter. Not sure why I didn't get better search results. The answer to his question is similar to mine but it was for a very different scenario. Sorry if it was too similar to his question. I'll try to do better research next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> MyList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> ''.join(MyList)

'abcde'
```

The solution to your other question

```
>>> MyList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> all(letter in MyList for letter in 'bad')
True

>>> all(letter in MyList for letter in 'test')
False
```

Comment: `from collections import Counter;bool(Counter'bed') - Counter('abcdef')`.  Note that `bool(Counter'cede') - Counter('abcdef')` would evaluate to `False` because `'abcdef'` does not have two `'e'`s in it.  If you wanted that to be `True` replace `Counter` with `set`.